# Python Tkinter Date picker using Combo box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to make a date picker using only combo box since I can't install tkcalendar. My problem is how to change the value combo box for day if I pick a certain cb for month. For example, April shouldn't have the day "31" or February shouldn't have day "30".

Here's what I've done so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")
root.resizable(False,False)

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
vlist = ["January up to December"]

vlist2 = ["1 up to 31"]

vlist3 = ["2015 up to 2040"]

vlist4 = ["1 up to 30"]

Combo = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = vlist, state='readonly')
Combo.set("Pick a month")
Combo.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

Combo2 = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = vlist2, state='readonly')
Combo2.set("Pick a day")
Combo2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

Combo3 = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = vlist3, state='readonly')
Combo3.set("Pick a year")
Combo3.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

def retrieve():
    if Combo.get() == "April":
        Combo2["values"] = (vlist4)
    else:
        Combo2["values"] = (vlist2)
    
    print(Combo.get(), Combo2.get(), Combo3.get())

Button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = retrieve)
Button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

I've only used April. I'll probably add more later.
Also, I'd shorten the values of vlist to avoid long code here.

I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: You could use a virtual event, like `combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func)` and func should configure the the combobox to get rid of the extra day

Comment: Why cant you use `tkcalendar`

Comment: You can use built-in `calendar` module to get the number of days for specified year and month.

Comment: "No module named tkcalendar appears", Idk why. I'd install all of it completely like "requirement already satisfied" always appears whenever I try it again. Also I tried all of of options that have been posted here and still cant fix it.

Comment: I'm gonna try the virtual event later. Hope you guys stay updated :)

Comment: You can also download the source code of tkcalendar and put it in your project folder

Comment: So I tried the virtual event `combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', func)` and it works. Thanks everyone ! Anyway tkcalendar still wont work, so maybe I'm gonna stick to this code.